# Expected value of absolute value of centered random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value, jensen-inequality

I am looking to prove the following:

> Given iid random variable's $X = X_1, X_2, \dots$, and mean $E[X] = \bar{X}$ ,show that:
>   $$E[|X|] \geq E[|X - \bar{X}|] \tag{1}\label{1}$$

This intuitively makes sense-clearly centering a random variable will bring it closer to $0$.

If there was no absolute value, applying linearity of expectation would show us:

$$E[X - \bar{X}] = E[X] - E[\bar{X}] = \bar{X} - \bar{X} = 0$$

And then noting that $E[|X|] \geq 0$, we can show that $E[|X|] \geq E[|X - \bar{X}|]$.

Is this all that is needed? In other words, is there a more formal way of proving $(1)$? I have considered using the fact that the absolute value function is convex, but am not sure if that is necessary to prove this.

#### Context

Updating this to include some additional context. I am asking this as part of a larger proof of the Weak Law of Law Numbers with infinite variance (part of *Discrete Stochastic Processes Theory for Applications* by Gallager). In it he states:

> **Theorem 1.7.4 (WLLN)**: For each integer $n \geq 1$, let $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$, where $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are IID rvs satisfying $E[|X|] < \infty$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$,
>   $$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P\Big( \Big| \frac{S_n}{n} - E[X]\Big| > \epsilon \Big) = 0$$ 
>   **Proof**: We use a truncation argument. Let $b$ be a positive number (which we later take to be increasing with $n$), and for each variable $X_i$, define a new rv $\hat{X}_i$ by:
>   $$
> \hat{X}_i = \begin{cases} 
>       X_i & for \; \; E[X] - b \leq X_i \leq E[X] + b \\
>       E[X] + b & for \; \;  X_i > E[X] + b \\
>       E[X] - b & for \; \; X_i < E[X] + b 
>    \end{cases}
> $$
>   The truncated variables are IID. Show that each $\hat{X}_i$ has a finite mean $E[\hat{X}]$ and a finite variance $\sigma_{\hat{X}}^2$. Show that the variance is upper bounded by the second moment around the original mean $\bar{X}$, i.e. show that $\sigma_{\hat{X}}^2 \leq bE[|\hat{X} - \bar{X}|] \leq 2bE[|X|]\tag{2}\label{2}$

It is this last step that prompted me to ask this question. I am not able to show that:

$$\sigma_{\hat{X}}^2 \leq bE[|\hat{X} - \bar{X}|] \leq 2bE[|X|]$$

I can prove the left side of the inequality, $\sigma_{\hat{X}}^2 \leq bE[|\hat{X} - \bar{X}|]$. Specifically, as $E[\hat{X}] \rightarrow E[X]$ the variance $\sigma_{\hat{X}}^2$ is maximized. Hence:

$$\sigma_{\hat{X}}^2 = Var(\hat{X}) = E[(\hat{X} - E[\hat{X}])^2]$$

Where this is maximized when $E[\hat{X}] = E[X]$:

$$\sigma_{\hat{X}}^2 \leq E[(\hat{X} - E[X])^2]$$

And we can show that $|\hat{X} - E[X]| \leq b$. Using this inequality we finally show:

$$\sigma_{\hat{X}}^2 \leq E[b^2] = bE[|\hat{X} - E[X]|]$$

So, that leaves me trying to prove the right hand side of the inequality in (2):

$$bE[|\hat{X} - \bar{X}|] \leq 2bE[|X|]$$

Which is why I asked the question of how to prove (1). My reasoning was that if I could prove (1), I could then prove the right hand side of the inequality in (2).

Comment: I don't understand your proof. You say "If there was no absolute value...", and then you arrive at the finished proof. But there is an absolute value! Think about it like this: If $Y$ were uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$, the expected value is $0$. Now what is the distribution of $|Y|$? Is it's expected value $0$ too?

Comment: What is the definition of $\overline{X}$?  If $\overline{X} = E[X_1]$, then why do we have the i.i.d. setup?  If $\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ for some positive integer $n$, then why are you treating $\overline{X}$ as a nonrandom constant in your analysis of the case without absolute value?

Comment: Why do you think (1) is true?

Comment: @T_M I completely understand what you are saying. The reason I added the "If there was no absolute value..." bit was just to show a bit of what I had been thinking. Of course the absolute value matters, and we can write: $E[|X|] \geq E[X]$.

Comment: @Michael I just updated the question to reflect that $E[X] = \bar{X}$. That is a good question though-my thought process was that since $E[E[X]] = E[X] = \bar{X}$, I could then treat it as a constant when it occurs inside of an expectation. As for I think it is true, first and foremost because I ran a few quick simulations to show that it holds in a variety of cases. Secondly, centering a random variable by subtracting it's mean should bring it closer to 0, and hence it should have a smaller expected value. (this is my thought process at least)

Comment: So then there is no reason for you to talk of i.i.d. random variables.  Your question is: If $X$ is a random variable with finite mean $m=E[X]$, do we always have $E[|X|]\geq E[|X-m|]$? The answer is no.

Comment: @Michael - I see what you are saying. I should have included the background of this question from the start. I updated the question to include the context, and hence why I was trying to prove that. It sounds like in order to complete my proof I will need to take another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Here is a counter-example:

$$X = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
1 & \mbox{ with prob $1/4$} \\
0 & \mbox{ with prob $3/4$} 
\end{array}\right.$$

Then

- $E[X]=1/4$.
- $E[|X|] = 1/4$
- $E[|X-1/4|] = 3/8 > 1/4$.

---

On the other hand, if $Y$ is any random variable with finite variance then 
$$ E[Y^2] \geq E[(Y-E[Y])^2]$$

---

Further, for any random variable $Y$ with finite mean we have 
$$E[|Y-E[Y]|] \leq 2E[|Y|]$$
Proof: 
$$|Y-E[Y]| \leq |Y| + |E[Y]| \leq |Y| + E[|Y|]$$
where the final inequality holds by Jensen's inequality with the convex function $|y|$. Taking expectations of both sides gives the result. $\Box$

[The example random variable $X$ given at the start of this answer indeed satisfies this inequality because $3/8\leq 2(1/4)$.]

Comment: Great counter-example. I have updated my question to reflect the context of which it is being asked (a proof of WLLN with infinite variance). I should have included that from the start, but I was trying to reduce the amount of text I was asking people to read in order to help solve this :)

Comment: I like the Gallager book.  In your updated question I think we have $\overline{X}=E[X]$.  So we always have $|\hat{X}-E[X]|\leq |X-E[X]|$ and we can apply the final fact in my edited answer.